# Unity3d, script for moving along x-axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written a script for moving by X-axis. It is called from another script in Update() if Input.GetKeyDown("left") (there is an object of this class).

But why does it work with different speed in build and in editor? Does it depend on Time.deltaTime?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveToSpecifiedAbscissa : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float AbscissaOfTheDestinantion;
    [SerializeField] private int Frequency;
    [SerializeField] private float Waiting;
    private float DisplacementByAbscissa;
    private bool IsMovingNow = false;

    public float GetTimeOfTheMoving()
    {
        return Waiting * (float)(Frequency);
    }

    public bool GetBoolVariableWhichSaysIfItIsMovingNow()
    {
        return IsMovingNow;
    }

    public void SetAbscissaOfTheDestinantion(float AbscissaToSave)
    {
        AbscissaOfTheDestinantion = AbscissaToSave;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        DisplacementByAbscissa = AbscissaOfTheDestinantion - transform.position.x;
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveAbstractly(int frequency, float waiting)
    {
        IsMovingNow = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < frequency; i++)
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(DisplacementByAbscissa * (1 / (float)(frequency)), 0, 0);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waiting);
        }
        IsMovingNow = false;
        StopCoroutine(MoveAbstractly(frequency, waiting));
    }

    public void Move()
    {
        StartCoroutine(MoveAbstractly(Frequency, Waiting));
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a simple time-based interpolation function instead of coroutines as the latter if used incorrectly is akin to `Application.DoEvents`.  Additionally it teaches bad habits from the perspective of a c# developer and will most likely lead to a lynching in a regular c# job.

Comment: By the way, your `StartCoroutine` is **unguarded** (no `if(xxx)`) so there is nothing stopping multiple coroutines to `MoveAbstractly` to run.   This is exactly like `Application.DoEvents` where your app has become re-entrant!

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you use `Update()` in the other script, which is called more or less depending on the current FrameRate. (Update is called once every new frame)
You could try calling your Movement via `FixedUpdate()` instead since it will be called frequently and does not depend on the FrameRate. I hope that fixes your problem! :)

Comment: No, it only starts the coroutine from Update(). The problem is in WaitForSeconds()... What about using async or threads?

Answer (score 0):

It is always safe to use time delta in transformations. As Pretzl already mentioned if you are calling the Move method from another script's Update method  you will be calling the Move method based on the current framerate that will lead to speed deviations of the object on different runtimes.

By the way maybe there are small deviations in time when calling method WaitForSeconds(). When program waits for next iteration in the coroutine I guess you should be calculating the difference based on time delta. It will be safe.